# Send video stream from iOS7 camera to JavaScript Canvas in web view

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, canvas, uiwebview

First a word of caution: this question is not suitable for the faint of heart. It is an interesting challenge that I have encountered recently. See if you can solve it or help in any way to get closer to an answer, at your own risk.

Here is the problem: Create an iOS application with a standard `UIWebView` inside. Obtain camera stream from either camera. Send each frame in a format that can be rendered into an HTML5 canvas. Make this happen efficiently so that video stream can be displayed at 720p 30fps or higher in an iOS7 device.

So far I have not found any solution that look promissing. In fact I started with the solution that looked most ridiculus which is encoding each frame in a base64 image string and passing it to web view via `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. Here is the method that does the JPEG encoding

```
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64StringJPEG:(UIImage *)image {
    return [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

Inside the `viewDidLoad` I create and configure the capture session

```
_output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

// create a queue to run the capture on
dispatch_queue_t captureQueue=dispatch_queue_create("captureQueue", NULL);

// setup output delegate
[_output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:captureQueue];

// configure the pixel format (could this be the problem? Is this suitable for JPEG?
_output.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
[_session addOutput:_output];
[_session startRunning];
```

The frames are captured and converted to `UIImage` first.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    _image = imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer);

    // here comes the ridiculus part. Attempt to encode the whole image and send it to JS land:
    _base64imgCmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"draw('data:image/png;base64,%@');", [self encodeToBase64StringJPEG:_image]];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:_base64imgCmd];
}
```

Guess what, it did not work. XCode is showing me this error:

```
DemoNativeToJS[3983:1803] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x15e9d460: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   0x355435d3 WebThreadLock
2   0x3013e2f9 <redacted>
3   0x7c3a1 -[igViewController captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:]
4   0x2c5bbe79 <redacted>
```

Is this error because WebView is running our of memory qouta? I should note that there is a big spike in the app memory usage just before crash. It crashes anywhere between 14MB to above 20MB depending on what the quality level is set for JPEG encoding.

[image]

I do not want to render the camera stream in native -- that wont be an interesting problem at all. I want to pass the video feed to JavaScript land and draw it inside the canvas.

For your convenience I have a [minimal demo project (XCode) on github](https://github.com/arasbm/DemoNativeToJS) that you can use to get a guick headstart:

```
git clone https://github.com/arasbm/DemoNativeToJS.git
```

Please let me know if you have other more sane ideas for passing the data through instead of using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`. If you have other ideas or suggestions feel free to let me know in comments, but I would expect the answer to demonstrate with some code what path will work.

Comment: Hello, did you find out how to improve fps?

Comment: @WorieN yes but this was ages ago I have no idea what I did and it probably would not apply to current version of the SDK anyway. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash you are experiencing is due to UIWebKit attempting to call UIKit from a background thread.  The easiest way to prevent this from happening is to force stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString which is making the call to UIKit to run in the main thread. You can do this by changing

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:_base64imgCmd];
```

To this

```
[self.webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:_base64imgCmd waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Which will now make the call to UIKit from the main execution thread, which will be safe.

Comment: I am seeing the video now on canvas at around 5FPS, not ideal but it is a big step forward. Thank you!